# Overwriting shp layer from temp layer in QGIS after Refactor field?

Tags: refactoring, qgis

I am at my wits' end on this issue and after scouring Google for 30 min, I still have no answer to this.

I have a shp layer with a field called "year" with integer values such as '2024', '2026' etc. I have been asked to make them ranges instead, e.g. '2024-2025'

To do this, I need to refactor the field from integer to string, using Toolbox->Refactor fields. Issues then arise:

- I cannot overwrite my shp layer when doing this, forcing me to make a temp layer.
- I cannot "save as" the temp layer to overwrite the existing layer, getting an error (shapefile.shp is not a directory.)
- Then, when I'm done and want to change the value in the Attribute table, **it refuses!** Instead of "2024-2025" as a string, it shows "-1" (the result?) for the field.

I have Layouts that depends on this layer, as I also need to do this change for a number of layers. This small change in all is causing me about an hour of work for each layer. The only other way out has been to make a new Field, but then all my symbology gets lost and I have to redo them manually for just this small change.

There simply must be a smarter way! What is happening since I cannot overwrite my shp file? Anyway I can skip temp layers completely? Anyway I can merge temp layer field to overwrite the shp layer field?

Is there an approachable way to do this when You have a deadline?

Thanks,

GregersDK